# Remove parts of a sentence in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am having a sentence as below

Eg:

Original Strings can be in below formats.

```
"[PartnerID:2012345][Failure] Caused by :This is the Failure Name"
"[Failure] caused by This is the failure name"
"Reliability: oscrash in This is the failure name"
```

I want the string to be trimmed to `This is the Failure Name`.

Can anyone please help me in writing code for this in python?
Sorry, I had left out other sentences before

Comment: What have you tried so far? Splitting a string is a very basic operation, do you need any advanced rules? What exactly *are* your rules for extracting the end of the sentence? The last 24 characters? Everything after ``:``, ``Cause by :``, or ``[Failure] Caused by :``? Are there any edge cases you do *not* want split, e.g. ``... Caused by: Invalid literal for int: 24.0`` would result in ``24.0`` or ``Invalid literal for int: 24.0``?

Comment: I had left out other sentences before. Apologies for that. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let:

```
str1 = "[PartnerID:2012345][Failure] Caused by :This is the Failure Name"
```

To get what you require, we split:

```
res = str1.split(":")[-1]
```

if it is like:

```
str1 = "[PartnerID:2012345][Failure] Caused by This is the Failure Name"
```

then you can:

```
res = str1.split("Caused by ")[-1]
```

Comment: Ok, If there are any variations in the sentence like [Failure] caused by This is the failure name, Then what can be done?

Comment: We need to know which part will be constant in your sentences. Maybe you can always split at `"[Failure]"` instead?

Comment: @VinyasBhat i've added that too. if this helps. dont forget to click the tick right next to my answe :)

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Come on, the failure name won't always start with a "T"... `split("Caused by")` is much more robust.